# asynctask doesn't seem to work in android service

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, rabbitmq

this is my android Notification Service that listen to a port and receives messages from a `RabbitMq` server, this code works well inside an `Activity` or `Fragment` but when i copy paste it to my service its not working! for example when it start consuming messages, if 10 new message is in queue Toast must show 10 but it show 0. ( inside an `Activity` it shows 10 ). it consume messages,means after running service queue will be empty but it dosent add to `ArrayList`. whats wrong ?

```
 public class NotificationService extends Service
    {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        Connection connection;
        Channel channel;
        String HostName = "192.168.2.11";
        String UserName = "o";
        String Password = "m";

        public void onCreate()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {

            String qName="0833";
            String routeKey="0833";
          new  AsyncSubscribe().execute(qName, routeKey);


            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        private class AsyncSubscribe extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
            Consumer consumer;
            ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {   
            }

                 @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {

                       consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                        @Override
                        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                                throws IOException {
                            properties.builder().deliveryMode(2);

                         // here we add messages to arraylist
                            messages.add(new String(body, "UTF-8"));

                        }
                    };
                    channel.basicConsume(params[0], true, consumer);



                }
                catch ( Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

 // here we show arraylist size
            Toast.makeText(NotificationService.this, Integer.toString( messages.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                try {


                    channel.close();
                    connection.close();



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }




        public void SubscribeSet() {


            try {
                factory.setHost(HostName);
                factory.setUsername(UserName);
                factory.setPassword(Password);
                connection = factory.newConnection();
                channel = connection.createChannel();
            }
            catch ( Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that you use an Asynctask in an Activity too?

Comment: doInBackground will long have finished when handleDelivery() triggers.

Comment: Your code should not work in an Activity either.

Comment: @greenapps no im not using Asynctask in an Activity! and it works in Activity fine.

Comment: 'this code works well inside an Activity'. So you lied. Please do not say such things if you do not use the same code. Then what is the reason that you would use an AsyncTask in the Service? I explained you already that your async task cannot work. But you did not react on that.

Comment: @greenapps its a misunderstanding! i have tried these codes in an Activity and it works well! but i do not use these codes at SAME TIME in an Activity and Services! So "doInBackground will long have finished when handleDelivery() triggers" i should test to find out its right or not , thanks any way